# Hide/Show new menus based on user's selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, cakephp-1.2

I have this menu:

```
Classificazione&nbsp;&nbsp;<select onchange="if(this.value == 'D'){ document.getElementById('menu2').style.display = 'block'; } else { document.getElementById('menu2').style.display = 'none'; }" style="margin-top: 5px;" name="classificazione">
            <option value="art0"></option>
            <option value="C" <?php if (isset($getParams['classificazione'])&&$getParams['classificazione']=="C") echo "selected"; ?> >Articoli</option>
            <option value="D" <?php if (isset($getParams['classificazione'])&&$getParams['classificazione']=="D") echo "selected"; ?> >Documentazione</option>
            <option value="A" <?php if (isset($getParams['classificazione'])&&$getParams['classificazione']=="A") echo "selected"; ?> >Libri</option>
            <option value="G" <?php if (isset($getParams['classificazione'])&&$getParams['classificazione']=="G") echo "selected"; ?> >Materiali</option>
            <option value="B" <?php if (isset($getParams['classificazione'])&&$getParams['classificazione']=="B") echo "selected"; ?> >Riviste</option>
      </select><br />
```

Only when the user selects the value 'Documentazione' I want to show another (equal) menu, with different option.
I added this submenu:

```
<select style="margin-top: 5px;" name="menu2">
            <option value="art0"></option>
            <option value="C" >Corsi</option>
            <option value="D" >Incontri</option>
            <option value="A" >Convegni</option>
            <option value="G" >Gruppi</option>
            <option value="B" >Progetto</option>
</select><br />
```

But it's not working

Comment: Do you want a sub-menu for every selection, or only if **Documentation** is selected?

Comment: Only when Documentation is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Classificazione&nbsp;&nbsp;<select onchange="if(this.value == 'D'){ document.getElementById('menu2').style.display = 'block'; } else { document.getElementById('menu2').style.display = 'none'; }" style="margin-top: 5px;" name="classificazione">
    <option value="art0"></option>
    <option value="C" <?php if ($getParams['classificazione']=="C") echo "selected"; ?> >Articoli</option>
    <option value="D" <?php if ($getParams['classificazione']=="D") echo "selected"; ?> >Documentazione</option>
    <option value="A" <?php if ($getParams['classificazione']=="A") echo "selected"; ?> >Libri</option>
    <option value="G" <?php if ($getParams['classificazione']=="G") echo "selected"; ?> >Materiali</option>
    <option value="B" <?php if ($getParams['classificazione']=="B") echo "selected"; ?> >Riviste</option>
</select>
```

notice the onchange event.

```
<select style="margin-top: 5px; display: none;" id="menu2">
        <option value="art0"></option>
        <option value="C" >Corsi</option>
        <option value="D" >Incontri</option>
        <option value="A" >Convegni</option>
        <option value="G" >Gruppi</option>
        <option value="B" >Progetto</option></select>
```

Comment: So now I have to do a new menu with: Submenu <select style="margin-top: 5px;" name="menu2"> <option value="foo"></option> ... ecc?

Comment: thats right, just make a new one and/or change the menu2 to something else, and make it display: none.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, because I can't get this working.

Comment: @Ettore i edited my answer, check out, you need to set menu2 as ID, not name, and add display: none on style.

Comment: How can I use 'LIKE' instead == ? for example if(this.value LIKE 'D') ?